# Is it possible to use Javascript to close Android Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, browser

I want to put a "close" button in a web page (our client wants to do that)
and when I click this button, I want to close Browser (not the current tab but "browser" in Android Browser, IE, Firefox, Chrome etc.).

I've searched around and found a method: `window.close()` but seems to only work on IE.
My question is:

**Is there any way to close Android Browser using Javascript?**

Comment: it only closes the current page/tab. Not sure if it closes tabs on mobile browsers, but it surely works on standard browsers

Comment: Why would you want to do that? As a user I would instantly hate any website that tried to close my browser.

Comment: @Dunes yeah, I don't want to do it too. But my client wants. And before telling them that they should not implement this feature. I want to find out all possible answers first

Comment: javascript:window.close(); doesn't work?

Comment: No, not working :-/ At least not on Android browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope - and that's a Good Thing: the webpage has no business messing with the browser itself ("wait, where did my window go? I had like 30 tabs in there - poof, gone!"), not to mention a glaring vulnerability:

1. insert an XSS into legitpage.example.com
2. when it gets activated, open a pop-under window of evilpage.example.net, which looks just like legitpage.example.com
3. close legitpage.example.com (if 2&3 are fast enough, the user may be fooled that xe's still on legitpage.example.com)
4. ???
5. Profit!

Comment: (note that on Android, there would be other unexpected side effects: the browser Activity gets popped off the stack and another Activity becomes active)

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, and never will be.

Answer (score 2):

`window.close()` actually works for Web Apps that were added to the home screen (with Chrome Beta).

It cleanly closes the app and gets back to the home screen.

Comment: This still works on android 8.0.0 (as of update 3 dec 2018) for sites added to desktop. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

Android browser allows JavaScript to close only popup windows. Hence there is no way to close window, unless it has been created as a popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple work-around for this would be to create an activity with full screen WebView control, display your HTML contents (local or from the Internet) there, and add a button to close this window, with a callback to Java to close this activity. Here is all the code you would need:

browser.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#404040"
          android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webkit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:visibility="visible"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

myBrowser.java activity (remember to declare it also in AndroidManifest.xml):

```
public class myBrowser extends Activity {
    protected WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // if you don't want app title bar...
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaCallback(), "JCB");

        // get the URL to navigate to, sent in Intent extra
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            String sUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
            if (sUrl != null)
                webView.loadUrl(sUrl);
        }
    }

    final public class MyJavaCallback {
        // this annotation is required in Jelly Bean and later:
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void finishActivity() {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The code to start this activity elsewhere in your app would be:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, myBrowser.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.someaddress.com/somepage.html");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and your somepage.html web page could have a "Close" button with the following code:

```
<button onclick="JCB.finishActivity()">Close</button>
```

You may add as well other buttons and callbacks for them to do what's needed in your Android Java code. Calls the other way - from Java to JavaScript on the page, are also possible, e.g.:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:functionName(params)");
```

Also, if you want to display content from Internet, not a local file or string in your WebView control, remember to add to AndroidManifest.xml the necessary permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Greg