# Javascript window close on Android browser

Tags: javascript, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use Javascript to close Android Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164242/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-close-android-browser)

I've developing a simple web page intended to run on Android browser. I must have a "Close" link which should close the browser window. On Chrome, having an `<a href="javascript:window.opener=self;self.close();">` does the job. However, it doesn't work on the Android browser. Is there a solution to accomplish this with Javascript?

Thanks in advance